# Blocktrail Bitcoin API receive payment

Tags: payment, bitcoin, blockchain

After I created an address, a webhook (on that address [address-transactions]), and sent BTC to that address, I am getting a callback.

How can I get the address, which was the purpose of payment (receive address)?

How can I be sure?

Callback below:

> {"network":"tBTC","event_type":"address-transactions","data":{"raw":"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","hash":"f7e57a938f1e1cb0edf3f32d3af1aeb5d97b6fed2cbcd13f72f31e3c49f9c299","first_seen_at":"2016-06-13T19:15:45+0000","last_seen_at":"2016-06-13T19:15:45+0000","block_height":870128,"block_time":"2016-06-13T20:41:54+0000","block_hash":"00000000002fc98e5a4b655daef4d609ecc64f3f4bd74220cc516e83e2359d30","confirmations":1,"is_coinbase":false,"estimated_value":400000,"total_input_value":4460000,"total_output_value":4456190,"total_fee":3810,"estimated_change":4056190,"estimated_change_address":"2MyCrfyKKb7LMsx5F4mmDVbwQSfEMspaopx","high_priority":false,"enough_fee":false,"contains_dust":false,"inputs":[{"index":0,"output_hash":"cadf9d987418db53779cbf2959f936f65ad8ef48e67fba9a2682a927132cb406","output_index":0,"value":4460000,"address":"2N4ufH2284xz1BEFnpi4rU2KZk9YUmtzTtT","type":"scripthash","multisig":null,"multisig_addresses":null,"script_signature":"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"}],"outputs":[{"index":0,"value":400000,"address":"2MsUxzFCWuiJJSouCHko2BkV9u3Md5q9D8T","type":"scripthash","multisig":null,"multisig_addresses":null,"script":"OP_HASH160
>   02994d31fb6c69f0a0399b879a7713130c75b894
>   OP_EQUAL","script_hex":"a91402994d31fb6c69f0a0399b879a7713130c75b89487","spent_hash":null,"spent_index":0},{"index":1,"value":4056190,"address":"2MyCrfyKKb7LMsx5F4mmDVbwQSfEMspaopx","type":"scripthash","multisig":null,"multisig_addresses":null,"script":"OP_HASH160
>   415e211a35874aad3561c72f79d36655bf1829fa
>   OP_EQUAL","script_hex":"a914415e211a35874aad3561c72f79d36655bf1829fa87","spent_hash":null,"spent_index":0}]},"retry_count":"6","addresses":{"2N4ufH2284xz1BEFnpi4rU2KZk9YUmtzTtT":-4460000}}

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The addresses portion in the last line (in your example) has the address. It is a key so you can use .keys() and select the first one. Here is an example of how I parsed it using python:

```
data = json.loads(request.body)
address = data['addresses'].keys()[0]
amount = data['addresses'][address]
confirmations = data['data']['confirmations']
```